# Checking if Android Gridview is scrolled to its top

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I want to determine if my Gridview is scrolled to its top.

Right now I'm using getChildAt(0).getTop() to do this. I save the value of getChildAt(0).getTop() on first draw and compare to getChildAt(0).getTop() on subsequent draws .

However, this seems hacky and seems to sometimes give me incorrect results.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `onScrollListener`

```
setOnScrollListener(this);

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    if(firstVisibleItem == 0){
        //do stuff here
    }

}
```

Comment: If the first item is visible it doesn't mean GridView is scrolled to top.

Answer (score 0):

The `getChildAt(0)` returns you the first visible item of the GridView and I guess that it's not what you want.

If you use `yourGridView.getFirstVisiblePosition()` method it will return the first visible position your data adapter, and that is what you want.

Comment: Hmm. I don't see how yourGridView.getFirstVisiblePosition() gives me what I want, unless I'm misunderstanding "visible." If the second row is the first row visible, I want the overall method I'm trying to write -- isGridScrolledToTop() -- to return false. It should return false in this case the grid isn't scrolled to its top. (It's scrolled to the second row.)

Comment: this isn't very accurate i find.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help, it works for me, good luck.

`yourGridView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                if(SCROLL_STATE_IDLE == scrollState) {
                    View view = view.getChildAt(0);
                    if(view != null) {
                        float y = view.getY();
                        Log.d("Tag", "first view Y is " + y);
                        if(y == 0) {
                            // do what you want
                        }
                    }
                }
            }`

Answer (score 0):

This's my answer:

```
mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
mListRV= (RecyclerView).findViewById(R.id.list_rv);
mListRV.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

mListRV.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        View v = mLayoutManager.getChildAt(0);
                        int offsetTop = v.getTop();
                        int offsetBottom = v.getBottom();
                        int height = (offsetBottom - offsetTop);
                        if(offsetTop >= -height/2) {
                            mListRV.smoothScrollBy(0, offsetTop);
                        } else {
                            mListRV.smoothScrollBy(0, height + offsetTop);
                        }
                    } 
                }
            });
```